# delay in applescript not delaying in loop

Tags: applescript, delay

I have the following applescript and for some reason it doesn't delay the amount of time specified. The way I understand it , it should delay 10 seconds between each display , but I get dialog after dialog without any delay

I've tried several different variants of this but it all ends up the same

```
set models to {"tom", "dick", "harry", "mark", "ringo", "john"}
set users to {"359597388", "338954297", "339380024", "1254012084", "265934082", "105804369"}
repeat
    repeat with model in models
        repeat with user in users
            delay (6000)
            display dialog "Sending user:" & user & "With model:" & model & "."

        end repeat

    end repeat
end repeat
```

Comment: The `delay` command takes an integer (**in seconds**) as its argument. You're telling the program to wait 6000 seconds, but it isn't working presumably because the program is timing out on you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
set models to {"tom", "dick", "harry", "mark", "ringo", "john"}
set users to {"359597388", "338954297", "339380024", "1254012084", "265934082", "105804369"}
repeat
    repeat with model in models
        repeat with user in users
            delay 10
            display dialog "Sending user:" & user & " With model: " & model & "."
        end repeat

    end repeat
end repeat
```